# How can I tell which process is IO bound?

Tags: io, top

Suppose I have a large number of processes and one (or more) is IO bound, obvious by a high `wa` value in `top`. How can I pinpoint which process it is? Each process shows how much cpu is being used, but how can I tell how much that process is causing the OS to wait due to IO?

Comment: just note that the OS is not holding up "waiting" during "I/O wait" -- it runs any other scheduled processes that are not themselves waiting on I/O.

Comment: `iotop` will tell you physical I/O rates

Comment: Although I'm not sure I disagree with this, I am less sure that I agree with it. Heavy IO can keep non-IO processes from responding.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1540/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-process-is-cpu-memory-or-disk-bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo iotop` gives you a nice, top-like overview of all disk io activty like this:

[image: iotop of tar cjvf ...]

To install, use `sudo apt-get install iotop`

Answer (score 2):

$ pidstat -d 5

Should print processes and their disk activity every 5 seconds. Pidstat can be found in the sysstat package.

$ sudo apt-get install sysstat